# Extending Walker_Nav_Menu in wp_nav_menu List of Empty Items

Tags: menus, walker

This has been confounding.

Trying to implement a WP nav walker for [pureCSS](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjx3vTM4P3VAhVpB8AKHdAsBaAQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpurecss.io%2F&usg=AFQjCNFDRDll-s-D10YFJVkFzKy85kBlog).

Found two seemingly easy routes via [this tutorial](https://corpocrat.com/2015/08/28/how-to-integrate-purecss-navigation-menu-into-wordpress) and [this gist](https://gist.github.com/moabi/22da47a56bcab30fb530696eddae70e9).

However I'm coming up with an empty menu!

The header:

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
    'theme_location'    => 'primary-navigation',
    'menu_class'        => 'pure-menu-list',
    'container_class'   => 'pure-menu pure-menu-horizontal',
    'walker'            => new pure_walker_nav_menu()
));
```

Without `'walker' => new pure_walker_nav_menu()` the menu is there.

In troubleshooting I have gone so far as to extend `Walker_Nav_Menu` without altering it both via an empty class and by duplicating it's code.

Result looks like this:

```
<nav>
    <div class="pure-menu-list">
         <ul>
             <li id="menu-item-8752" class="menu-item-8752 pure-menu-item">
                 <a></a>
             </li>
             etc...
```

So I must be doing something wrong somewhere, but can't seem to track down the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that the theme location is `primary_navigation` with an underscore, not `primary-navigation` with a hyphen.

I'm not sure why it seemed to work without the `walker` argument.

Typical and along the lines of what it seemed like must be the solution. The obvious thing I wasn't seeing because of feeling overwhelmed by an area I'm still not totally at home with, that being extending the `Walker_Nav_Menu`.